# FFMPEG via PHP - background task for generating thumbnail not producing

Tags: php, shell, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail from a video using FFMPEG via PHP.

This is working great if I do:

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -vframes 1 THUMB.png');
```

But with help from [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) I tried to turn this into a background process. It runs, but I don't get any file (THUMB.jpg) written to the server.

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -vframes 1 THUMB.png </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/log/ffmpeg.log &');
```

Perhaps it IS generating the thumg but in a different place from where it generates it when I run it synchronously within my PHP flow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should always specify absolute pathnames for everything. That would be the first thing I'd change.

Comment: And there's no reason to redirect STDIN and STDOUT. You can remove `</dev/null >/dev/null `

Comment: Well this CMD syntax is very new on me so I basically just copied it from the reference site. I don't quite understand what redirecting STDIN and STDOUT means. I just tried prefixing my input.mp4 and THUMB.png paths with `/home/myusername/public_html/` but no change... is that what you mean?

Comment: Really just putting `&` after your original code should work fine.

Comment: Fixed, thank you. If it's working (even as a background task) without absolute paths, why do you say I should specify them as absolute?

Comment: Because it's safer to know where files are going to be created. You don't have to hard-code the paths in, you can use magic constants like `__DIR__` to place it relative to the source file.

Comment: And letting your web server write to the same directory your PHP files are in is a bad idea.

Comment: Check if you have a `/var/log/ffmpeg.log` and whether it's being updated when you run this command. I'm guessing that the script doesn't have write access to `/var/log` (or that specific file because you tested it as a different user) and therefore fails to start the command.

Comment: @thatotherguy actually I couldn't find that... there's no `var` folder on my server. I even looked in CPanel file editor, unless it's hiding dirs from me.

Comment: @miken32 - but this is where I need the images to be output, so my webpage can access them. What is proposed instead? What's the risk here?

Comment: There's your problem then. Write the log to `/tmp/ffmpeg.log` or `/dev/null` instead, anywhere that exists where the script has write access.